# Pandas: return rows that have two matching columns commonality

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, match

I am trying to write a commonality script which will return rows in a pandas dataframe that have two matching columns, and also will sum up the number of rows with matches into a new column

OPERATION and MACHINE are the columns to match

Input:

| BATCH | OPERATION | MACHINE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 4000 | Printer1 | 01-Jan-22 |
| 1A | 2000 | Fax1 | 02-Jan-22 |
| 1B | 4000 | Printer2 | 03-Jan-22 |
| 1B | 2000 | Phone1 | 04-Jan-22 |
| 1C | 2000 | Phone2 | 05-Jan-22 |
| 1A | 2000 | Phone2 | 06-Jan-22 |

Output: just the last two rows in this example with OPERATION =2000 and MACHINE = Phone2

| BATCH | OPERATION | MACHINE | DATE | MATCHES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1C | 2000 | Phone2 | 05-Jan-22 | 2 |
| 1A | 2000 | Phone2 | 06-Jan-22 | 2 |

I have tried several merge and duplicated df commands but can't get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[df.groupby(['OPERATION', 'MACHINE'])['BATCH'].transform('count') > 1].assign(MATCHES = df.groupby(['OPERATION', 'MACHINE'])['BATCH'].transform('count'))

  BATCH  OPERATION MACHINE       DATE  MATCHES
4    1C       2000  Phone2  05-Jan-22        2
5    1A       2000  Phone2  06-Jan-22        2
```

OR

```
df['MATCHES'] = df.groupby(['OPERATION', 'MACHINE'])['BATCH'].transform('count')
df[df['MATCHES']>1]
```

Note: one may be faster than other depending on the source dataframe